# Ubuntu refuses to load after a successful installation

Tags: boot, 14.04, toshiba

I installed 14.04 with default settings and when I turn off the laptop and turn it back on, Ubuntu refuses to boot up, instead asks me to insert a Boot Device.

Here's the paste text from the boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7464628/

The machine is Toshiba C55-a-1m7.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You are still in UEFI mode right?  Your setup looks OK for a secure UEFI boot.

Comment: Check you do not have legacy boot enabled in BIOS.

Comment: No, it says "Boot mode UEFI" or something similar in BIOS. I should mention I am installing 14.04

Comment: Check the bios settings mentioned in answers to [Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode (unable to boot from USB)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/374931/install-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode-unable-to-boot-from-usb)

Comment: Also, you did use the amd64 install of Ubuntu 14.04, and not the 32-bit version?

Comment: Also check if there are any BIOS upgrades for your laptop

Comment: I used the 14.04 amd version, the BIOS settings are similar to that link (disabled secure mode, UEFI boot), not sure how to check for BIOS upgrades actually. Please help, I am this close to buying a Windows 7 installation tomorrow since I am leaving for a trip and it's 2AM here.

Comment: I've also tried this and it gave me a few errors about blocklists and GPT: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1633758

Comment: When I use the boot-repair tool, and go to the advanced options the GRUB location is greyed out... might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: first post from this thread: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=708430

Use a live CD and replace "debian" with "ubuntu"

```
mkdir /target
mount /dev/sda2 /target
mount /dev/sda1 /target/boot/efi
mount --bind /sys /target/sys
mount --bind /proc /target/proc
mount --bind /dev /target/dev
chroot /target

cd /boot/efi/EFI
mkdir boot
cp debian/grubx64.efi boot/bootx64.efi
```

I also had to add sudo in front of all commands up to "chroot".

Comment: Thanks for directing us to this.  I'm not sure if it's required, but I also see instructions about unmounting those directories before rebooting. https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall