# I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04LTS and stuck at grub terminal. What should I do now?

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, live-usb

I previously have fedora installed on my laptop. Now I wanna shift to Ubuntu. So I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04LTS ISO image file and using Rufus software I made my USB drive bootable. But when I plug in my USB drive to my laptop, my laptop screen stucks at grub terminal. And now I even can't get into my fedora. What should I do now ? Please help !

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Are you booting in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Should use what system is and all since 2012 are UEFI.  Rufus may make either CSM (UEFI) or UEFI versions of installer. CSM is BIOS emulation in UEFI.  Some just find using different tool to make flash drive or different flash drive then works.

Comment: I have Dell Inspiron 15series

Comment: Then what model 15, Dell seems to use that for many versions. Just about all Dell are the same. More difference if AMD or Intel based. https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-is/sln298524/how-to-use-and-troubleshoot-the-inspiron-17-5759?lang=en&ref=topsolutions#Resetting_System_Setup
How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me and I solved it by deactivating the secure boot in the BIOS options. Neither RUSFUS or UNETBOOTIN were behind the problem, only the secure mode thing in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I copied this from 
[Stuck at GRUB command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line)

You got a problem with the bootloader. You should initialize kernel. First use command ls, then adjust the following commands according to it. In the place of hd0 write your disk and in 1 write your number.
FIRST, try only `grub> boot`

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic 
grub> initrd /initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
grub> boot
```

If you don't know what your version of the kernel is, write:

```
grub> linux /vmlTab
grub> initrd /inTab
```

Comment: I don't have any partitions

Answer (score 0):

**If you are able to boot on your live Linux USB**, then you might try to reinstall Grub on your booting partition: take a loot at the steps described there https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/. This operation should be farely safe considering that you are not doing anything in the main partition, but do not hesitate to do a backup of your files before. This worked for me when I was stuck at grub terminal after I tried installing Ubuntu.

**If you are not able to boot on your live Linux USB**, then the booting settings of your computer are probably not suitable to the ISO file burned on the drive. This seems to be a common issue with Dell Inspiron laptops. Try the steps described there: https://askubuntu.com/a/920272/1066357.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I re-flashed my USB using Unetbootin software. And it worked. My laptop successfully booted into Ubuntu desktop 18.04. Rufus didn't help.