# Creating bootable USB drive for Ubuntu on UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb

I have Ubuntu (latest version) installed on a Toshiba laptop which has UEFI, and need to update the BIOS.

Toshiba provides BIOS updates as EXE files. I do not have Windows as dual boot, so I tried to create a live USB with freedos installed and boot from that, to then run the EXE file. I have tried multiple times now using multiple methods, and the USB drive will not boot. I even tried to create a live USB with Win10 and that failed also. The USB drives boots just fine on another laptop that does not use UEFI, but not on the laptop that does. So I presume that the USB drive is not being set up correctly to be recognised as bootable on the Toshiba UEFI laptop?

This question is linked to an earlier question ([EXT4-fs error on Toshiba Tecra with WD SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196252/ext4-fs-error-on-toshiba-tecra-with-wd-ssd)) so you can see the methods I tried (with thanks to @heynnema). These include using UNetbootin and mkusb.

Any help would be much appreciated as I really need to update the BIOS.

Comment: You can create a Windows installer drive, that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185).

Comment: [You cannot expect FreeDOS to boot in UEFI mode](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/UEFI). But you should be able to go into your UEFI/BIOS menus and switch the boot mode from UEFI to BIOS (alias CSM alias legacy mode). And then your drive with FreeDOS should be able to boot.

Comment: Rufus has an image option for Windows To Go. This offers a Full install of Windows on bootable USB. The process is slow and may not work on all flashdrives. A 15GB drive may be OK if you just want to run an EXE file. Windows will soon start asking you to register it, but it will still mostly work. I recall Rufus only gives a UEFI option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try toggling the UEFI setting on your BIOS. Keeping in mind when you update the BIOS, you may have to change the UEFI settings again.